# MediaPipe TensorflowLite Iris Model

Tags: computer-vision, tensorflow-lite, mediapipe

I am trying to understand the output of the tflite [Iris landmarks model](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/models/iris_landmark.tflite) available from mediapipe.

The [model card](https://mediapipe.page.link/iris-mc)
describes the output as 71 2D landmarks and 5 2D landmarks.  When inspecting the model as follows:

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path='iris_landmark.tflite')
interpreter.allocate_tensors()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()

print(output_details)
[{'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'index': 384,
  'name': 'output_eyes_contours_and_brows',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
   'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([  1, 213], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([  1, 213], dtype=int32),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'index': 385,
  'name': 'output_iris',
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'quantized_dimension': 0,
   'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32)},
  'shape': array([ 1, 15], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([ 1, 15], dtype=int32),
  'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

I see 213 values and 15 values in the model outputs - so I assume I am getting an x/y/z coordinate for each point.  After running the model on an image I get values in the -7000 to +7000 range.  My input was a 64x64 image, any idea of how these points correspond to the original image?

I would like to have pixel coordinates of the eye keypoints, which are rendered in the mediapipe examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model card appears to be wrong, it actually outputs 3D coordinates, there are also some normalization on the model input and output that isn't clear, but is used for drawing the 2d landmarks.

I opened a github issue with my findings [here](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/1041).  I haven't seen any changes related to the model card.

I created a colab demonstrating proper usage, [here](https://github.com/shortcipher3/stackoverflow/blob/master/mediapipe_iris_2d_landmarks.ipynb).  You can ignore the z coordinate and plot the x/y coordinates onto your image to see the landmarks.

I probably should update the colab with an iris picture example.